# What does "Shocks/Chills enemies as though dealing X% more damage" mean?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've noticed a few skills, such as [Ice Shot](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Ice_Shot) and [Lightning Arrow](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Lightning_Arrow) with the text *"Chills/Shocks enemies as though dealing X% more damage"*. I'm not really sure what this means, most likely because I have no idea how status ailments work in Path of Exile. I've tried searching online, but all the results I found so far just discuss whether this effect is additive or multiplicative, which isn't exactly helpful when I don't understand what these abilities mean to begin with.

What do these effects mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Status ailments](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Ailment) in Path of Exile are based on the damage of the hit. For instance, in your case:

- Cold damage always inflicts chill. Chill slows all actions of the affected target up to 30%, **based on the cold damage of the hit.** The base duration is 2 seconds.
- Shock causes the affected target to take up to 50% increased damage from all sources, **based on the lightning damage of the hit**. The base duration is 2 seconds.

You can read up on the way damage calculations are made here:

- [Shock](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Shock#Mechanics)
- [Chill](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Chill#Mechanics)

Essentially, the "Chills/Shocks enemies as though dealing X% more damage" will calculate your skill's chance to chill based on an increased damage modifier of your damage dealt.  Take a hypothetical scenario where you deal 100 cold damage to the enemy. A level 1 Ice Shot has a "Chilled enemies as though dealing 100% more damage".  Instead of your chill effect being based off 100 damage, it would instead be based off the base damage "as if it was 100% more damage", thus making your chill effect based off "200 damage", despite you not dealing that much.

Basically, it increases your threshold to apply the chill/shock in the first place, since a higher damage value is being used in the calculation of that effect being applied.

Comment: So one thing I'm confused on, is that the wiki makes mention of skills having an "X% chance to inflict chill/shock". Is this outdated information?

Comment: There is an additional step of checking the HP values of the monster for some status effects. For instance, the lowest application of shock that can be achieved is 5%. If the damage that hits that enemy inflicts shock but cannot reach a high enough threshold to meet that minimum level, it will not deal shock, regardless of your shock chance.

Comment: @Wipqozn You need to have a chance to inflict freeze/shock/ignite in order to be able to inflict said ailment. Some skills have it, some don't. For instance, the skill Doryani's Touch on the unique gloves Doryani's Fists has an innate 20% chance to shock on hit. Critical strikes will always have a 100% chance to inflict an ailment, given that the Painseeker gloves are not equipped.

Answer (score 3):

They way status elements proc is if you successfully roll a status proc based on your the chance to inflict status, and the enemy fails to resist the status, or if you inflict a critical strike.

Status effects, such as shocked which allows you to deal up to 50% more damage, are based on the amount of damage you do. The higher the damage you do when you proc shock, the higher the percentage of extra damage you will be able to have on a shocked enemy, with a minimum of 5% and max of 50%. The exact formula is shown below, where D is your total damage that can shock, T is is the enemy's ailment threshold (normally their max health), and M is the sum of the attacker's increases to the effect of shock (comes from X% increased effect of shock modifiers).

[image: status effect forumla]

So, shocks as if dealing X% more damage modifiers help increase the effectiveness of you shock procs, similarly to X% increased effect of shock modifiers.

See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/ea2639/voltaxic_shock_enemies_as_though_dealing_300_more/fanfiq0/) for a more in depth explanation.